# Intermittent Request Failure with RDC endpoints

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We've been doing some testing with the RDC endpoints in Banno and noticed a bizzare issue where, intermittently, a POST request will respond with a 400. Seconds later, submitting the same request will yield a new RDC account as expected. I'm doing my testing in PowerShell, and below are some examples.

```
New-RDCAccount -userId $userId -accountTypeMarker Checking -name "Text" -accountNumber "XXXXXXXXX"
```

And the response for this would work, however when I send a request minutes later:

```
New-RDCAccount -userId $userId -accountTypeMarker Checking -name "Text" -accountNumber "XXXXXXXXX" 
#Note that $userId is the same throughout each request
```

I get this response: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

I understand that the error code implies that my body is malformed, but how is it possible that in one request it's acceptable and in the next it's malformed?

Below is the body for each request (with redacted information). The first one is a working example, and the second one is the failed example:

```
{
"accountNumber":  "XXXXXXXX",
"accountTypeMarker":  "Checking",
"name":  "Text"
}

{
"accountNumber":  "XXXXXXXX",
"accountTypeMarker":  "Checking",
"name":  "Text"
}
```

Because I feel this issue is a little hard to believe, I've provided screenshots as well with this.

Not working:

[image]

Working:

[image]

I'm hopeful someone here can help me out here, cause I feel like I'm taking crazy pills looking at this.

Thank you!

Edit:

Here's another example of it working on one instance, and not another with 0 changes to the code (side by side):

[image]

Edit of edit:

I can replicate this issue pretty consistently through Banno People AND my own PowerShell script. I feel this is definitely something on the Banno side at this point...

Pictures for Jamies comment:

Working request headers:
[image]

Fail request headers (Note that accessing any of the elements yield a null result):

[image]

I'm using this endpoint: https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/rdc/details/#/User%20RDC%20Endpoints/post_a_mobile_api_v0_institutions__institutionId__users__userId__rdcAccounts

Comment: Can you edit the script to log the `x-request-id` for each of the responses? That, plus information on the approximate day+time when this behavior occurred will make it easier for Engineering to understand what is happening. (Also if you have the redacted form of the URLs being used, that's also useful so we know precisely which endpoints are being used.)

Comment: Hi Jamie, it doesn't look like I'm getting a x-request-id back from the response. I see it in the header, but its value is null. I don't see a way to add images to the comment, so I'll add them to the bottom of the post instead. On a successful GET, I can get a x-request-id back

Comment: Hi Jamie, perhaps I wasn't doing something right in PoweShell to get the header values back, but I was able to get a request ID by attempting to create a new RDC account through Banno People. The failed request id :

x-request-id: 6d4429c956222f0480a31ed16958ae3d

Comment: Hi Jamie, I had another employee try this on their machine and they got the same errro. Request id: x-request-id:e328bf09d1a48d9807c781b7cbaf4c3

Comment: Ok, I ended up figuring out the issue with PowerShell not providing me with the x-request-id headers. Below are a bunch of request IDs and timestamps :

request id                         date

f24033834fe6fad2836f5edaf57ec1d4 08/17/2022 14:09:24
c7319bfa0a48b3029a9ca27544aaff1c 08/17/2022 14:09:24
92781e36cd24612ec2f639b50bbd0767 08/17/2022 14:09:22
6c1450f68ae8f3dea36d39cb45f1d164 08/17/2022 14:09:20
0e0b1d4016319df59ff2951c8321012b 08/17/2022 14:10:47
ad3c556362057264af8139d7c1f05547 08/17/2022 14:11:20
f1c29db558103ae4bc38becb3db442ff 08/17/2022 14:12:15

Comment: @JaimeLopezJr. I promise this is the last edit on this: Below is a working request id:

b0496d32706603cc3ed62d282bfcd419

and a non-working one with the same body


e37c5309c70112adb6661fb76b1b198d 08/17/2022 14:25:17

And another working one, after it had failed:

d8570fcf52a699f5da9fea07ef1113e3 Date: Wed, 17 Aug 2022 19:26:22 GMT

I hope this gives you everything you're looking for,

Comment: Thank you, those request IDs will be helpful.

Comment: Some info from Engineering. For `x-request-id` `6d4429c956222f0480a31ed16958ae3d` we're getting something odd back from EPS, which we'll have to investigate further to figure out the HTTP 400 error.

Comment: For `x-request-id` `e328bf09d1a48d9807c781b7cbaf4c3` that isn't matching anything in the logs, which has us wondering if that is a copy-and-paste error? Missing a character?

Comment: All of the requests in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73366209/intermittent-request-failure-with-rdc-endpoints#comment129612342_73366209 (example `x-request-id` `f24033834fe6fad2836f5edaf57ec1d4` failed with HTTP 401 due to an _expired_ Access Token. The Access Tokens are time-limited, so if you have an expired Access Token then you'll need to authenticate again for a new one.

Comment: Gotcha, that was my bad on the unauthorized ones, I was testing with the raw invoke-restmethod cmdlet itself rather than the function which catches if the token is invalid. If you need more requests I'd be happy to get them to you without an unauthroized batch.

Comment: Yes, please get some additional requests with a _valid_ Access Token which fail. That'll be helpful for Engineering.

Comment: 8a74949789d4bc3131c59bf28154dc9a 08/19/2022 08:56:58 (fail)
f4ece1010198d500d3ebd0d46480648a 08/19/2022 08:57:53 (fail)
8be1807da13d1b6e12675ccf23d59ec3 08/19/2022 09:09:20 (fail)
243438106f830547746026bb7a7cd3f0 Fri, 19 Aug 2022 14:09:52 GMT (success)
691c34ba11e99f46e0b6185c2648e43d 08/19/2022 09:10:41 (fail)
181f56a741ab230a971cb282465e210b 08/19/2022 09:11:23 (fail)
d086329efcaec70569aaaa6bdb7e377e 08/19/2022 09:11:45 (fail)
9b08ce725b6056f26eb5ec5a11ddbebb Fri, 19 Aug 2022 14:11:48 GMT (success)

Hope this gives you what you need.

Comment: That'll be helpful for Engineering. We'll take a look.

Comment: Engineering is wondering if you are "trying to create multiple RDC accounts with the same account number and type, which EPS may not allow". Can you provide some insight?

Comment: Also, it seems as though figuring out precisely what is occurring in your case is obscured by the fact that your institution is using an 'older' version of the EPS integration, where the error messages are not as legible. The 'newer' EPS integration apparently has more helpful error messages.

Comment: The suggestion, at this point, is to open up a jSource case since it appears as though the issue isn't within Banno's API per se but perhaps somewhere deeper within EPS. Sorry for having to go that route, but that'll help bring in the correct teams and make sure everyone is on the same page with the data.

Comment: "trying to create multiple RDC accounts with the same account number and type, which EPS may not allow" - that's not the goal of the finished product, however while in the testing I may have "tried" doing that, there should still be examples of where there was not an existing RDC account at the time of the request. You may be onto something though - I wonder if it takes some time for the information from Banno to propagate to the EPS side? See fbb479640267f458b5e778c47d44074e 08/22/2022 21:36:40 for example, this account does not currently exist but it still failed

Comment: I can still create a new account with a fresh, never used account number (like 12345789). However an account like this one, which is not *currently* in the accounts' RDC listing (99a589de807f11f0c95bcff5a581e512 08/22/2022 21:39:41) fails. but when I change the number slightly it works. Note the 21:39:41 request's account hadn't been used since many days prior, so I'm thinking there's some weekly/monthly purge that may occur to get rid of stale account number.

Comment: So my consensus then is that we are unable to create a new RDC account that has an account number that had *previously* been in Banno, or is currently in that particular accounts' Banno RDC account list. I submitted this post because it wasn't something I expected to come across in testing. I'm not sure of the business impact of the above scenario but I imagine it's small. I will continue my testing by incrementing the account number rather than attempting to use the same account numbers repeatedly. Beyond that, I imagine someone should fix the scenario listed above, if that is indeed the case

Comment: And of course, now that I try the above scenario again it works... I was able to create 3 RDC accounts with the same account number.  But if I try the accounts that were deleted, it still fails... So, I don't know at this point what the issue is. But thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry we couldn't resolve it here, but at least we've sniffed out some possibilities. Creating a jSource case to have the EPS folks look at your scenarios might be good to track things down. Might also be good to consider upgrading to the newer EPS integration, if that's workable.